# Что сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки ОДИН открывался контейнер и когда я нажимаю на кнопку ДВА предыдущий контейнер закрывался и открывался новый?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть кнопки, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, у меня появляется контейнер (по умолчанию у него Visible = false), то есть не появляется, а точнее сказать отображается(смотреть код, что бы понятно было). Так вот, что мне нужно написать в коде, что бы когда я нажал на одну кнопку отобразился этот контейнер, и когда я нажму на вторую кнопку, предыдущий контейнер закрылся(что бы Visible снова стал = false) и отобразился другой контейнер, который принадлежит второй кнопке. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил ситуацию.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо создать отдельный метод для этого функционала. Входным параметром нужно передавать какой контейнер нужно показывать. В методе все контейнеры скрывай, а в конце у того контейнера который нужно показать, просто ставишь флаг видимости.